# Multilabel for text with word2vec

Tags: python

I'm new to text classification and found this simple Looking tutorial here, which seems to be a good start for further development:

https://asinayev.github.io/choosing-multiple-labels-for-text-part-2-word2vec.html

I added the following Imports to the Code found on that Web page:

```
import regex as re
import stopwords
import string
import scipy
import gensim.models.keyedvectors as word2vec
```

I changed the original Code from:

```
 from gensim.models import Word2Vec
```

to:

```
 import gensim.models.keyedvectors as word2vec
```

and also load the model according to recent changes in gensim with:

```
 model = word2vec.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('asd.bin.gz')
```

To test if the model loads correctly I use (and it does):

```
print(model.most_similar('teacher'))
```

Here is the copy&paste part, which Ends in an error:

```
def clean(sentence, model):
regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
tokens = str.split(sentence)
cleans = []
for t in tokens:
    if t in model: 
        cleans.append(t)
    elif t.lower() in model: 
        cleans.append(t.lower())
    elif regex.sub('_', t) in model:
        cleans.append(regex.sub('_', t))
    elif len(str.split(regex.sub(' ', t))) > 1:
        for token in str.split(regex.sub(' ', t)):
            if clean(token): cleans.append(clean(token)[0])
cleans = [w for w in cleans if w not in stopwords.words("english")]
return cleans

def model_similarity (model, list1, list2, l1neg=[], l2neg=[]):
list1sum = sum([model[l] for l in list1])
list2sum = sum([model[l] for l in list2])
if l1neg: list1sum -= sum([model[l] for l in l1neg])
if l2neg: list1sum -= sum([model[l] for l in l2neg])
return 1-scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(list1sum,list2sum)
```

To test if the functions work, I test them with:

```
model_similarity(clean('king woman'),clean('queen'), l1neg=['man'])
TypeError: clean() missing 1 required positional argument: 'model'
```

To be honest I'm not sure that a positional Argument is and therefore struggle to fix it.

Thanks for your effort!

Additional informations: I'm using Python 3.6.5 on Windows 10

Edit: Solved this issues:

Correct Call for the function is:

```
 model_similarity(model, clean('king woman', model), clean('queen', model))
 0.6532526016235352
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the definition of model_similarity() that you wrote:

```
def model_similarity (model, list1, list2, l1neg=[], l2neg=[]):
```

python expects the first three arguments to be the model, list1, and list2. These are called positional arguments because you list them in the definition without a name followed by an equals sign (as you do for l1neg and l2neg). Looks like you forgot to include the model. See *positional* vs. *keyword* arguments here: https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html

It looks like you also forgot to include the model in your calls to clean().

So the call would look like:

```
def model_similarity (model, clean('king woman', model), clean('queen', model) l1neg=[], l2neg=[]):
```

Also, make sure to indent the code after the all function definitions. Looks like there might be other issues as well.

Comment: Thank you! The glossary will be very helpful!

 The call you suggest gives me a Syntax error.